# passing table name as argument to a function create a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this function as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_table(tableName varchar)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %L(
        link_id integer NOT NULL);',tableName);

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
ALTER FUNCTION create_table(varchar)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

suppose I execute the function like this:

```
select * from create_table('me')
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'me'"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'me'(
                                   ^
QUERY:  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'me'(
        link_id integer NOT NULL);
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function create_table(character varying) line 4 at EXECUTE statement

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "'me'"
SQL state: 42601
Context: PL/pgSQL function create_table(character varying) line 4 at EXECUTE statement
```

Could you please let me know what this error mean and how to solve it?
thanks

Comment: Your function returns void so you can't select from it's results.  Also, I'm not sure about postgresql but in at least one other database engines, ms sql, functions are not allowed to write to the database.  They can only return data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation for `format`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT):

> - `I` treats the argument value as an SQL identifier, double-quoting it if necessary.
> - `L` quotes the argument value as an SQL literal.

You want the former, not the latter. So:

```
   EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I(
        link_id integer NOT NULL);',tableName);
```

(Disclaimer: I don't have PostgreSQL instance handy to test with, so there may still be some other problems after you correct the `%L` to `%I`.)